# Ubuntu Nautilus can't see SMB file share

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba

On my "Other locations" section, i used to be able to see my NAS server, however i had trouble with connecting to it. In the middle of poking around settings i must have messed something up and now it doesn't appear in the list anymore. It can still be accessed by directly inserting the address on the bottom, and in the meanwhile i have managed to figure out how to access it correctly, however the problem of it not being visible in the list persists. As a note, it is visible on all other computers in the network (on Linux Mint, ZorinOS and Windows as well). How do i fix this.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using where the problem is?

Comment: did you add the NAS in `fstab` and if so [edit] your question with the entry used.